# PHP Curl get all action in log file

Tags: php, sockets, curl, encode

I have a PHP **ENCODED** script that use **CURL** to connect to other servers.
so I want to get all URL that this script access via CURL.

Is it possible to LOG all CURL action in text file ?
How could this possible ?

Should I change any thing in error_reporting in PHP ?

Is it possible to use Firewall or anything else to monitor PHP sockets ?

Thank you

Comment: do you really mean **encoded**? as to the questions: yes; by writing code; no; yes - but just do 1

Comment: Hi, Script encode via Ioncube so its not possible to decode it or add or bind a code into it.

Comment: well the obvious approach is work with the source. otherwise network traffic sniffing will be evolved.

Comment: Can we see code what you have tried?

Comment: As I wrote before, soruce code is encoded via ioncube and its not open to read it ! I want to know that is it possible to LOG Curl via php.ini configuration

Comment: encoded by who and why? i suspect its something brought that does  a licence check your trying get around - tell me it s not so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, you can use TCPDUMP to dump all tcp connection and you can filter the host destination on it.

Thank you